# Solving a system of equations using R

Tags: r, numerical-methods

I'm trying to use R for my Macro practise and model solve for the equilibrium price where the inverse demand curve PD(q) and supply curve P.

How do i do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124351/discussion-on-question-by-tara-solving-a-system-of-equations-using-r).

Answer (score 4):

Note 1.: It is rude to edit a question after it was answered; I had to make significant edits to make my answer consistent.

---

Note 2.: this is not a system of equations. There are two functions defined, but only one equation:
$$P_D(q) - P_S(q) = 0$$

---

What helps here is that inverse demand is decreasing in quantity while inverse supply is increasing. So given any $q$, if $P_D(q) > P_S(q)$ we know that $q$ is under the equilibrium value of $q^*$, and if $P_D(q) < P_S(q)$ then $q > q^*$.

You can also narrow down the range $q^*$ can be found in. Clearly $q^* \geq 0$.

Also $P_D(q)$ should not dip into negative territory, so you can find a very large $\bar{q}$ for which $P_D(q) \leq 0$. One can do this easily by starting from $\bar{q} = 1$, evaluating $P_D(\bar{q})$, and doubling $\bar{q} = 1$ iff $P_D(\bar{q}) > 0$.

Given the interval $I = [0, \bar{q}]$ which we know contains $q^*$, you can now apply [*interval halving*](http://boron.physics.metu.edu.tr/NumericalComputations/ceng375/node32.html).

An algorithm for approximating $q^*$ with a desired level of precision $\epsilon$:

---

Define the interval $I = [0, \bar{q}]$.

**Start of LOOP** 
Select the midpoint of the interval as a "guess" for $q^*$. (In the first iteration this is $q = \bar{q}/2$.)

Evaluate the statement $P_D(q) > P_S(q)$. 
**If true**, then

$q^*$ should be smaller, the solution is in the lower half of the interval, so in the next iteration we will use that as our new interval $I$. 
**If false**, then

$q^*$ should be larger, the solution is in the upper half of the interval, so in the next iteration we will use that as our new interval $I$.

Evaluate the statement *new interval is very small*, i.e. has length less than $2\epsilon$. 
**If true**, then 
select its midpoint and say that you have approximated $q^*$ with reasonable precision, end program. 
**If false**, then 
Go to start of LOOP.

Comment: Thorough answer. But once you have $\bar q$, you can simply use `optimize` to minimize the absolute difference over the relevant interval---will work fine since the functions are presumably monotone. This is probably easier and more efficient than writing your own interval-halving algorithm.

Comment: @kyle I've never heard of this function before. (I mostly used R for econometrics.) If you were to write a short answer based on your comment (explaining what the function does) that would be lovely!

Answer (score 2):

This builds on @Giskard's answer above.

Once you know the range of feasible market-clearing quantities, $q \in [ 0, \bar q ]$, you can directly apply R's `uniroot` function ([R manual](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/uniroot)), which searches a given interval for the zeros of a function.

```
# What are my demand and supply functions? 1 - q and q, because economics.
P_D <- function ( q ) { 1 - q }
P_S <- function ( q ) { q }

# Set @Giskard's upper bound for the search
qbar <- 1

# Find the equilibrium quantity
uniroot( function ( q ) { P_D( q ) - P_S( q ) }, lower = 0, upper = qbar )

##########
# OUTPUT #
##########
#
# $root
# [1] 0.5
#
# $f.root
# [1] 0
#
# $iter
# [1] 1
#
# $init.it
# [1] NA
#
# $estim.prec
# [1] 0.5
```

After you find the intersection, verify that `$.root == 0`, or is within a tolerance of zero.

If you are lazy, you can set `qbar <- 1e9` (for example) and it will still behave reasonably nicely. Do be cautious if you take this approach, in case your demand and supply functions are nonmonotone on economically-irrelevant intervals.

---

Per my comment on @Giskard's answer, you could also implement this search as

```
optimize( function ( q ) { abs( P_D( q ) - P_S( q ) ) }, interval = c( 0, qbar ) )
```

However, R has a built-in root-finding function (`uniroot`), so why not use it.